# How to Read and reply emails automatically at server

Tags: asp.net, email

I know how to send email from a server if the "To" is known like just,

public class SentEmail : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string Sending_Email(string strEmailAddrFrom, 
string[] strEmailAddrTo, int intTotalEmailTo, string strAttachement)
    {
        EmailAlert NewMail = new EmailAlert();
        return NewMail.EmailSent(strEmailAddrFrom, 
    strEmailAddrTo, intTotalEmailTo, strAttachement);
    }
}
```

But the problem is how to read all the incoming emails(probably from gmail) continuously at the server(where web service is written),
and detect the sender ex: abc@xyz.com... and reply to him.
This is some sort of autoreply but need to reply for detected sender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a service to poll your email box.  You could use something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/ to communicate with gmail's POP3 servers.